# If I uninstall VMWare Player in windows 7 in order to upgrade, do I lose my VM?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have a VMWare Player 4.0.2.  I can upgrade it to version 5.0.0.  I started the process and it asked me to uninstall the current version of VMWare.  I am afraid of losing my VM inside the VMWare Player. I have a Ubuntu 12.04 as a guest OS inside the VMPlayer.

Obviously, I can create a latest version of VMWare 5.0.0 and create a new VM Ubuntu insdie it, then I will have to migrate all my applications insdie the Ubuntu into the new VM.  This seems to be lots of work.  My hope is to simply upgrade my VMWare Player without affecting the VM inside it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Previous version upgrades would NOT delete the VMs. And if they did it would be extremely weird, like getting all PDFs deleted when you upgrade acrobat reader.

Comment: Vmware defualt setting makes directory under `Documents\Virtual Machines` and all your VMs should be there  .

Answer (score 4):

It will leave existing VMs intact. I have seen the GUI forget the location of the VM and then you have to manually open it rather than just clicking on its tab. But so long as you know the folder the VM is stored in, that's the most minor of inconveniences.

Comment: It worked beautifully.  Thanks so much.  I was able to upgrde to 5.0.0, then upgrade again to 5.0.1.  In each upgrade, I had to remove the previous version, and then install a new version.  I was able to start VM without any glitches.